# Access to instance of fullCalendar v5

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I initialed fullCalendar v5 in my react app like this:

```
class CalendarComponent extends Component {
   
  state = { searchable: false, dateable: false }


   componentDidMount() {
    this.initialCalendar();        
   }

initialCalendar() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, momentPlugin, timeGridPlugin ],
   .
   .
   .
});

calendar.render();
}

handleGoToDate(event) {
if (event.key === 'Enter') { 
  // Have access to instance of calendar here and perform this function 
   calendar.gotoDate(this._go_date.value);      
}
}

render() {
 return (
  <div id="calendar"/>

  <input type='text'
    id="inputGoDate"            
    ref={(c) => this._go_date = c}
    onKeyDown={this.handleGoToDate.bind(this)}/>
 )
}
}
```

Everything works as it supposed to work , now I would like to have access to instance of `fullCalendar` to use `gotoDate()` function in a function outside of `initialcalendar()` function. How can I have an instance of `fullCalendar`? So far I tried to use   `calendarComponentRef = React.createRef()` in my component but it did not work. It looks like if I want to use `React.createRef()` I have to initial my calendar in another way. I am looking for a solution to have access to instance of calendar in a way that I do not need to change the way I initialed calendar. Is there a way to have access to instance of calendar in this way?

Comment: You know you don't need to build your own integration between fullCalendar and React - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react

Answer (score 0):

ADyson is right. You shouldn't be mixing React and native Javascript like that.

Follow the React setup docs here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react

Then once you did that to access the Calendar object you have to see the "Calendar API" section. See this example code:

```
export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {

  calendarRef = React.createRef()

  render() {
    return (
      <FullCalendar ref={this.calendarRef} plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]} />
    )
  }

  someMethod() {
    let calendarApi = this.calendarRef.current.getApi()
    calendarApi.next()
  }

}
```